# Compare two xml files and highlight the differences

Tags: c#, xml

I could use some help with something i need to solve.
I have two xml files and they are almost identical, i need to find what was changed, which means, i need to compare them line by line, and i need to highlight the changes in Visual Studio using c#

I've seen the tools but i would like to know if i can do it using code.
I'm new to this so i could use a little guide.

My xml files are something like:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Employees>
  <Employee ID="1" Name="JayT" JoinDate="3/1/2009">
    <Projects>
      <Project ID="1" Name="Project1" StartDate="2/1/2009" EndDate="4/1/2009" />
      <Project ID="2" Name="Project2" StartDate="3/5/2009" EndDate="4/1/2010" />
    </Projects>
  </Employee>
  <Employee ID="2" Name="Kim" JoinDate="4/1/2009">
    <Projects>
      <Project ID="3" Name="Project3" StartDate="5/1/2009" EndDate="10/1/2009" />
      <Project ID="2" Name="Project2" StartDate="3/5/2009" EndDate="4/1/2010" />
      <Project ID="6" Name="Project6" StartDate="3/5/2009" EndDate="4/1/2010" />
    </Projects>
  </Employee>
  <Employee ID="3" Name="Tom" JoinDate="6/1/2009">
    <Projects>
    </Projects>
  </Employee>
</Employees> 

File2 Data: Modified File (Referred to as "B XML" in the document) 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Employees>
  <Employee ID="1" Name="JayT" JoinDate="3/1/2009">
    <Projects>
      <Project ID="6" Name="Project6" StartDate="5/1/2009" EndDate="11/1/2009" />
    </Projects>   
  </Employee>
  <Employee ID="3" Name="Tom" JoinDate="6/1/2009">
    <Projects>
      <Project ID="5" Name="Project5" StartDate="7/1/2009" EndDate="12/1/2009" />
    </Projects>   
  </Employee> 
</Employees>
```

For example the code above, i need to highlight the changes, the rows added or removed

Comment: Can you give an example of two "almost identical" xml files. And what the desired output of the comparison should be?

Comment: They are almost identical, i.e the Label of one button is"red" and the other file that same button has "blue", so the files are identical, just some attributes change. I ould like to highlight the change rows with c#

Comment: A diff app seems to be the answer here - I user winmerge but there are others out there - and IDEs such as VisualStudio have them included.

Comment: The thing is i nee the c# code because i need to implement them in another software

Comment: I would have a class, with a function, two variables which are the two xml files, an compare them line by line.

The xml are used in another software to build an interface, i need to implement c# code to find the differences and highlight them in the graphical part

Comment: write two sample xml to compare and your desired (highlighted) output

Comment: @fex, i edited the question with a sample, the idea is the same

Answer (score 0):

You can use XMLDocument class to load both the files and then compare each node's value and attributes using string comparison and possibly save the changes in a third xmldocument.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx